# How can I test GRE packets connectivity?

Tags: networking, connectivity

If desiring to **test** TCP port `5900` to a remote host (say IP `111.222.111.222` ), I do :

```
l$ nc -v 111.222.111.222 5901
Connection to localhost 5901 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
RFB 003.008
```

As can be seen, **NetCat** reports `succeeded` , and I can even read the starting header (RFB in this case, because the protocol is `VNC` ) of the communication.

Is there a similar method to **test GRE** connectivity?

NetCat would be a good tool for this, as long as it is widely implemented, but other tools or methods will be allowed, of course.

For this example, I think we can assume we have a **listening remote PPTP** server with TCP port 1723 correctly open (PPTP requires GRE packets allowed).

Answer (score 1):

you can use `tcpdump` to verify

```
tcpdump -nvi any proto gre

15:50:49.834143 IP 20.0.0.2 > 20.0.0.1: GREv1, call 24, seq 0, length 26: LCP, Conf-Request (0x01), id 0, length 12
15:50:51.857988 IP 20.0.0.1 > 20.0.0.2: GREv1, call 1, seq 1, ack 4294967295, length 34: LCP, Conf-Request (0x01), id 1, length 16
15:50:51.858092 IP 20.0.0.2 > 20.0.0.1: GREv1, call 24, seq 1, ack 1, length 34: LCP, Conf-Ack (0x02), id 1, length 16
15:51:00.192601 IP 20.0.0.2 > 20.0.0.1: GREv1, call 24, seq 2, length 26: LCP, Conf-Request (0x01), id 1, length 12
15:51:00.193207 IP 20.0.0.1 > 20.0.0.2: GREv1, call 1, seq 2, ack 2, length 30: LCP, Conf-Ack (0x02), id 1, length 12
15:51:00.193289 IP 20.0.0.2 > 20.0.0.1: GREv1, call 24, seq 3, ack 2, length 34: PAP, Auth-Req (0x01), id 0, Peer ixia, Name ixia
15:51:00.219147 IP 20.0.0.1 > 20.0.0.2: GREv1, call 1, seq 3, ack 3, length 25: PAP, Auth-ACK (0x02), id 0, Msg 
15:51:00.219231 IP 20.0.0.2 > 20.0.0.1: GREv1, call 24, seq 4, ack 3, length 30: IPCP, Conf-Request (0x01), id 0, length 12
15:51:00.219259 IP 20.0.0.1 > 20.0.0.2: GREv1, call 1, seq 4, ack 3, length 30: IPCP, Conf-Request (0x01), id 1, length 12
15:51:00.219321 IP 20.0.0.2 > 20.0.0.1: GREv1, call 24, seq 5, ack 4, length 30: IPCP, Conf-Ack (0x02), id 1, length 12
15:51:00.221903 IP 20.0.0.1 > 20.0.0.2: GREv1, call 1, seq 5, ack 5, length 30: IPCP, Conf-Nack (0x03), id 0, length 12
15:51:00.221962 IP 20.0.0.2 > 20.0.0.1: GREv1, call 24, seq 6, ack 5, length 30: IPCP, Conf-Request (0x01), id 1, length 12
15:51:00.222481 IP 20.0.0.1 > 20.0.0.2: GREv1, call 1, seq 6, ack 6, length 30: IPCP, Conf-Ack (0x02), id 1, length 12
15:51:00.721559 IP 20.0.0.2 > 20.0.0.1: GREv1, call 24, ack 6, no-payload, length 12
15:52:00.197893 IP 20.0.0.2 > 20.0.0.1: GREv1, call 24, seq 7, length 100: IP 17.1.1.122 > testforchris2.am.lilly.com: ICMP echo request, id 6187, seq 1, length 64
15:52:00.198930 IP 20.0.0.1 > 20.0.0.2: GREv1, call 1, seq 7, ack 7, length 104: IP testforchris2.am.lilly.com > 17.1.1.122: ICMP echo reply, id 6187, seq 1, length 64
15:52:00.697808 IP 20.0.0.2 > 20.0.0.1: GREv1, call 24, ack 7, no-payload, length 12
```

Comment: Well, this is not a bad solution: each A to B packet should have a corresponding B to A packet. Indeed, I have checked two cases: one of them with GRE blocked and another one with GRE allowed, and, as expected, there is no B to A answer. Simple, portable and even easily scriptable. Thanks you, Binarysta.

Comment: you're welcome, you can add `-vvv` for more details, in case needed for scripting.